# Xamarin.Forms PullToRefresh not occuring when ListView is empty?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Forms I have a simple ListView that is bound to a view model using MVVM.

```
  <ListView Grid.Row="1"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding ContactsGrouped}"
                     IsGroupingEnabled="true"
                     IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                     RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
                     IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
                     GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Key}"
                     GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding Key}"
                     BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                     SelectionMode="Single"
                     HasUnevenRows="true" 
                     SeparatorColor="#cccccc">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <cr:MyItemTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

This is my xaml code, which works perfectly fine if the list has at least 1 item. By tapping and pulling down on the item, the list view refreshes fine, however tapping and pulling down outside of the item, the list does not cause PullToRefresh to occur. It's almost as if the ListView has transparent input but its items do not, thus allowing it to work.

Anything in the red in my example image shows the area where if I tap and drag down the activity indicator appears fine and the refresh happens. Tap and dragging anywhere in the green however causes the View to not refresh and the activity indicator to not appear.
[image: Example]

I won't show my view model as the issue is with the View. I've also tried setting background color to red, checking if transparent was causing an issue, sadly that is not the case. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by pulling down outside of the item? If the listView is empty, can you see the Activity Indicator when you pull to refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reproduced your problem on my side. After some researching, I found it is known issue from Xamarin.forms 3.5.0 and it still exist in `Latest stable 3.6.0.344457`.

The **WorkAround** is downgrade your Xamarin.forms version to `3.4.0`.

Also, I test it in the Latest prerelease `4.0.0.394984-pre10` and it works well. So, I believe this issue will be solved in the next release version.

You can follow this [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5268) to check the process.

Comment: I updated Xamarin to version 4.5 and the problem still occurs

Answer (score 0):

Try adding VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand".

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ContactsGrouped}"
    IsGroupingEnabled="true"
    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
    RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
    IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
    GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Key}"
    GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding Key}"
    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    HasUnevenRows="true" 
    SeparatorColor="#cccccc"
    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <cr:MyItemTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This property tells the View how much space of your screen should it cover. If you don't add it then the View will just cover whatever the required length to display the data it needs.

Comment: Have you made a typo here, should it be VerticalOptions?
Please show how you would add this to the code given in the question (copy and paste the code and add your suggestion) and explain what the VerticalOptions attribute setting does. This will go a long way to improving your answer and rep.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the ListView does fill the whole space. I've checked that by setting the background of it to red. The issue is, when I tap and drag down on the list view, the refresh doesn't occur but if I tap and pull down on an item in the list view it works fine. So if the list view is empty, I can't refresh.

Comment: I think if List view is having no item pull to refresh doesn't work than you have to again assign list items.